# bootstrap progress bar does not display

Tags: php, html, mysql, bootstrap-4

i have to display the progress of some task. retrieved data from mysql to show the progress of the task. my code is here

```
<h4>Task 1</h4>
                    <div class="progress progress-striped">
                    <?php

  $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root", "", "db1");

 $query = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table1` Group by `ID`");
 $query->execute();
 $query->store_result();

 $rows = $query->num_rows;

 $percentage = $rows/120 * 100;

  ?>


<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="<?php echo $percentage; ?>%">


 <?php echo $percentage; ?>%

                          </div>
                        </div>
```

but my progress bar is not displaying its empty. as my table contains 4 records

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax, as found [here in the documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/progress/) is:

```
   <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
```

So your percentage needs to be in aria-valuenow:

```
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="<?php echo $percentage; ?>" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
```

Comment: but there is one problem progress bar does not show any color

Comment: Please refer to the link in the answer. It shows you how to add colour as well as lots of other customisations.

Comment: if i removed style width then it does not show color

Comment: then put style width back. You didn't have style width before, it also doesn't have to be the percentage that you get, but any value you like.